# Is there any issue if I kill sync() process before it finished

Tags: linux, synchronization

On panic situation, I want to set timeout for sync() system call. In the case this timeout value is passed, I want to kill sync process and reboot the system.

I wonder if there is any issue with that behivior?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible at all to kill a `sync()` call. Killing the process which has done it is probably not enough.

If cancelling `sync()` is possible then I would expect the damage to be less than without calling it, at least when using a journalled filesystem.

It may be useful to do this call as early as possible (i.e. before killing tasks). That may allow you to use a longer timeout.

Comment: If you do `sync` before killing tasks, that won't take into account any writing that the tasks do (including deleting files whose link count dropped to 0 because all the processes that had them open died, which happens even on a SIGKILL).

Comment: @Gilles Indeed my statement was too short. I didn't want to suggest to call `sync()` only once. My point was that the more can be written the earlier you start flushing the buffers. Taking everything into account doesn't help if there is not enough time left to write all of it. But to get both advantages you need several calls. Maybe it's even better than repeating the calls to remount the volumes with `sync`. That would avoid storage idle times but on the other hand prevent access optimization on rotating disks.